# Millenial Media Ads doesn't appear in Android app

Tags: android, ads

Newbie of Android coding, I've published an Android app on Play Store and I'd like to monetize through Ads with Millenial Media.

Already register a new account, I followed every guides in their site, still I can't figure out why Ads won't show up in my app when launched.

The codes in attachment show just the instructions i added to my app in order to visualize mm ads.

This is my Android Manifest modified to implements MMedia Ads:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" 
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" ></activity>

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Here is MainActivity.java with codes for MMads

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MMAdView adViewFromXml;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    adViewFromXml=(MMAdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);

    MMRequest request = new MMRequest();

    adViewFromXml.setMMRequest(request);
    adViewFromXml.getAd();
```

And here is activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:mm="http://millennialmedia.com/android/schema"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rlLayout" >

 <!-- The android layout width and height should match the mm width and height -->
<com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    mm:width="320"
    mm:height="50"
    mm:apid="XXXXX"
    mm:refreshInterval="20"
    mm:accelerate="true"
    mm:age="30"
    mm:gender="male"

     />
```

I already linked my Android device to MMedia portal to receive testing ads through Device ID; 
I've imported the MMedia library required and integrated the MM sdk;

Still, when i launch my Android App, the Ad Banner doesn't show up. No error warning.

As guide, I've also followed this Youtube Video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNQoSRI6vks

Any advice is highly appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: MMedia Support gave me another APID (a dummy one for test purpose), and it worked. So i assume my codes are correct.

Comment: How did you find this dummy apid?

Comment: I asked to their Customer Service via email, they answered me back with a new (and functional) APID. Sorry, cannot be more precise because it was so long time ago.